# Get all instances of a class in PHP

Tags: php, class, dynamic

I would like to get all the instances of an object of a certain class.

For example:

```
class Foo {
}

$a = new Foo();
$b = new Foo();

$instances = get_instances_of_class('Foo');
```

`$instances` should be either `array($a, $b)` or `array($b, $a)` (order does not matter).

A plus is if the function would return instances which have a superclass of the requested class, though this isn't necessary.

One method I can think of is using a static class member variable which holds an array of instances.  In the class's constructor and destructor, I would add or remove `$this` from the array.  This is rather troublesome and error-prone if I have to do it on many classes.

Comment: Why do you feel that you need this?

Comment: @troelskn, I need this because I am making an event system and need to be able to sent events to all objects of a certain class (a global notification, if you will, which is dynamically bound).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you derive all your objects from a TrackableObject class, this class could be set up to handle such things (just be sure you call `parent::__construct()` and `parent::__destruct()` when overloading those in subclasses.

```
class TrackableObject
{
    protected static $_instances = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$_instances[] = $this;
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        unset(self::$_instances[array_search($this, self::$_instances, true)]);
    }

    /**
     * @param $includeSubclasses Optionally include subclasses in returned set
     * @returns array array of objects
     */
    public static function getInstances($includeSubclasses = false)
    {
        $return = array();
        foreach(self::$_instances as $instance) {
            if ($instance instanceof get_class($this)) {
                if ($includeSubclasses || (get_class($instance) === get_class($this)) {
                    $return[] = $instance;
                }
            }
        }
        return $return;
    }
}
```

The major issue with this is that no object would be automatically picked up by garbage collection (as a reference to it still exists within `TrackableObject::$_instances`), so `__destruct()` would need to be called manually to destroy said object. (Circular Reference Garbage Collection was added in PHP 5.3 and may present additional garbage collection opportunities)

Comment: This was basically my initial idea.  I'll try and implement it.

Comment: Question: wouldn't getInstances be static?

Comment: Yes, it would, it was quite late when I typed this up, but you are indeed correct, Sir.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a possible solution:

```
function get_instances_of_class($class) {
    $instances = array();

    foreach ($GLOBALS as $value) {
        if (is_a($value, $class) || is_subclass_of($value, $class)) {
            array_push($instances, $value);
        }
    }

    return $instances;
}
```

**Edit**: Updated the code to check if the `$class` is a superclass.

**Edit 2**: Made a slightly messier recursive function that checks each object's variables instead of just the top-level objects:

```
function get_instances_of_class($class, $vars=null) {
    if ($vars == null) {
        $vars = $GLOBALS;
    }

    $instances = array();

    foreach ($vars as $value) {
        if (is_a($value, $class)) {
            array_push($instances, $value);
        }

        $object_vars = get_object_vars($value);
        if ($object_vars) {
            $instances = array_merge($instances, get_instances_of_class($class, $object_vars));
        }
    }

    return $instances;
}
```

I'm not sure if it can go into infinite recursion with certain objects, so beware...

Comment: This doesn't work as well as I would like.  Most of my instances are members of some other classes.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a recursive function that looks for instances in all the members of all objects (and all the members of those members, ...).

Comment: There's another problem: temporary variables.  I don't think you can cover all corners with $GLOBALS, which would introduce unexpected bugs most likely.  I'm sure your method would be useful for someone else, though, with less specific needs.

Comment: `get_object_vars` will only return the public members. you would have to use Reflection to find instances in non-public members.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the PHP runtime does not expose the underlying object space, so it would not be possible to query it for instances of an object.

Comment: Do you have any sources to confirm this?

Answer (score 2):

> I need this because I am making an event system and need to be able to sent events to all objects of a certain class (a global notification, if you will, which is dynamically bound).

I would suggest having a separate object where you register objects with (An [observer pattern](http://books.google.dk/books?id=qVLjFk_4zVYC&pg=PA207&lpg=PA207&dq=spl+php+observer+pattern&source=bl&ots=fOaPhg0VSl&sig=IWa5RzL40ypycRU6Rfj0B-O8AJ4&hl=da&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=8&ct=result#PPA207,M1)). PHP has built-in support for this, through spl; See: [SplObserver](http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/interfaceSplObserver.html) and [SplSubject](http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/interfaceSplSubject.html).

Comment: I would like a system more like Qt's signals and slots.  The behavior I want in particular is as such: I have ChatRoom classes, which fire an event messageSent when someone sends a message.  I would like a MessageFilter class to filter ANY message sent through ANY ChatRoom.

Comment: So you want a global observer? You can either create a global variable, or you can pass the same instance to all ChatRoom's