# Listing all objects of a certain class

Tags: php, oop

Ok my problem is as follows;

I have a class that describes a pet with this constructor;

```
public function __construct($name, $type, $age)
```

So what I want to do is make a number of pet objects, then I want to print all the attributes of all the objects of this class so that it looks something like [this](http://www.ia.hiof.no/~kyvh/dynamicWeb/images/pets.jpg)

What is the best way of going about it? I know how to iterate through an object's variables, but my main concern is how to iterate through all objects of a certain class. I would love it if someone could show me a code example of something, particularly if there is a way to do it without the use of arrays.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475569/get-all-instances-of-a-class-in-php/483094

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would expect to have some way of tracking the instances you've created, maybe in an array or some kind of containing class.

But for the sake of argument, you could check all the variables in the current scope with [get_defined_vars()](http://php.net/get_defined_Vars), recursively searching any arrays or objects you find, with something like this:

```
function findInstancesOf($classname, $vars)
{
    foreach($vars as $name=>$var)
    {
        if (is_a($var, classname)) 
        {
             //dump it here
             echo "$name is a $classname<br>";

        }
        elseif(is_array($var))
        {
             //recursively search array     
             findInstancesOf($classname, $var);
        }
        elseif(is_object($var))
        {
             //recursively search object members
             $members=get_object_var($var);     
             findInstancesOf($classname, $members);
        }
    }
}

$vars = get_defined_vars();
findInstancesOf('MyPetClass', $vars);
```

Answer (score 6):

You could, in the class constructor, append `$this` to a static array that keeps all the elements of this type:

```
class Pet {
    public static $allPets = array();
    function __construct($name, $type, $age) {
        self::$allPets[] = $this;
        // more construction
    }
}
```

Your list of all Pet objects is now in `Pet::$allPets`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on your structure, but I´d have another object / class that contains all generated pet objects, so I would loop through that.

Comment: perhaps an example of how to create this object would help?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could make a custom create option and use static variables to store an instance of each created class

```
Class Pet
{
     public static $pets = array();
     public static create($name, $type, $age)
     {
         $pet = new Pet($name, $type, $age);
         self::$pets[] = $pet;
         return $pet;
     }
}
Pet::createPet("test", "test", 42);
Pet::createPet("test", "test", 42);
Pet::createPet("test", "test", 42);

foreach(Pet::$pets as $pet)
{
    echo $pet->name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i would make a foreach loop

```
foreach($myobject as $key => $pent)
{
 echo $key;
 echo $pent;

}
```