# Get all objects of a particular class

Tags: php, oop, class, reflection

i have to list objects that are instance of a class by refrence

```
class Foo {}
class Foo1 {}
$obj1 = new Foo;
$obj2 = new Foo;
$obj32 = new Foo1;
```

i need a solution to get all objects that are instance of Foo class
do you know how to do that ?

Comment: are you dynamically creating them?

Comment: What does all mean? In the global or in the local variable space or even both? Which variable names do you use? Can you extend the class to make it recordkeeping of instances?

Comment: by all instances of Foo, do you also mean all instances of subclasses?  If there was a class Foo2 extends Foo {} for example, would you want all the Foo2 objects as well?

Comment: @GordonM: no, i need just object of Foo. that's not important that Foo2 extends Foo

Comment: @hakre: all in the both local and global scope

Comment: @Omid Amraei: See my answer, it provides such an array for `Foo`. If you need the extended classes as well, take care that the constructor is called.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get all instances of a class in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475569/get-all-instances-of-a-class-in-php)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A solution to get all instances of a class is to keep records of instantiated classes when you create them:

```
class Foo
{
  static $instances=array();
  public function __construct() {
    Foo::$instances[] = $this;
  }
}
```

Now the globally accessible array `Foo::$instances` will contain all instances of that class. Your question was a bit broad so I can not exactly say if this is what you're looking for. If not, it hopefully helps to make it more clear what you're looking for.

Comment: wouldn't this prevent GC of removing this object ?

Comment: Not only GC, these objects are not destructed even, so GC won't even kick in. So you need to clean yourself (`Foo::$instances = [];`).

Answer (score 2):

See this answer [Get all instances of a class in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475569/get-all-instances-of-a-class-in-php) has worked for me to do this in the past.