# How do I iterate over instances of a class

Tags: php, oop

Is there a way to iterate over all instances of a class in PHP? I can do it manually by counting them with a static variable as they are created, but I would prefer to be able to make a static method that would apply to each instance of a class.

For example, say I have a class called Ball that creates a unique ID and set of characteristics for each ball via its constructor. The Ball class has a method to generate the CSS for that specific ball via a method called getCSSrule(). I would like to create a static method called getCSS() that would call the getCSSrule() for each existing ball that writes out the entire CSS block for all of the balls that currently exist. Then instead of calling $obj->getCSSrule() for each ball I could just call Ball::getCSS() once.

```
public static function getCSS(){
  $css;
  foreach(Ball as $obj){
    $css += $obj->getCSSrule();
  }
  return $css;
}
```

The foreach doesn't seem to work either as a static method in the class or as a function outside of the class. Currently I have to make an array of the ball names and use that to find each instance of the class. Thanks!

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you want to do. Clarify the question please. Maybe remove all implementation details and just state your setup/scenario and what your desired output/goal is.

Comment: Seems similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475569/get-all-instances-of-a-class-in-php)

Comment: Good find parkker007, I missed that one.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. You answered my question very well. Your first approach worked very well and I will vote for it when my reputation allows me to do that... I also really like the second approach and will test it soon.

Answer (score 1):

> Currently I have to make an array of the ball names and use that to find each instance of the class.

That is the correct way to achieve what you are trying to do.  A slightly more OO-approach would utilize a collection class of some sort (e.g., `BallPit`, as noted in Daff's answer), but the principle is the same.

There are other approaches, such as creating a sort of hybrid [multiton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern) (unlike a traditional multiton, it wouldn't limit the number of instances that can be created, but one would only be able to create new instances via a static method of the owning class which would manage the array of created instances).

But if you are (or might someday be) using automated testing for your application, it will cause massive headaches for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm pretty sure that you have to keep track of the actual instances (not just their names) somewhere, somehow. E.g. in a class *BallPit* or your main script that contains a list of balls. This would also be the place where you iterate through the lists and get each instances CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The literal answer following your given implementation details would be something like

```
class Ball
{
    protected static $balls = array();
    protected $cssRule;

    public function __construct($cssRule)
    {
        self::$balls[] = $this;
        $this->cssRule = $cssRule;
    }
    public static function getCss()
    {
        $css = '';
        foreach (self::$balls as $ball) {
            $css .= $ball->getCssRule();
        }
        return $css;
    }
    public function getCssRule()
    {
        return $this->cssRule;
    }
}
```

In other words, you can collect the created instances in a static property. You could then do what you ask for in your question, e.g. ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/4Kzxgg))

```
new Ball('foo');
new Ball('bar');
new Ball('baz');
echo Ball::getCSS();
```

which would then print foobarbaz. Whether this is a good approach is a different question. An alternative I'd prefer would be something like this:

```
class Balls implements IteratorAggregate
{
    protected $balls;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->balls = new SplObjectStorage;
    }
    public function attach(Ball $ball)
    {
        $this->balls->attach($ball);
    }
    public function detach(Ball $ball)
    {
        $this->balls->detach($ball);
    }
    public function getIterator()
    {
        return clone($this->balls);
    }
    public function create($cssRule)
    {
        $ball = new Ball($cssRule);
        $this->attach($ball);
        return $ball;
    }
}
```

You could then do

```
$balls = new Balls;
$balls->create('foo');
$balls->create('bar');
$balls->create('baz');
```

to create new `Ball` instances, which will be automatically stored in `Balls`. And because `Balls` is an `IteratorAggregate` you can simply iterate over all the instances within with `foreach`, e.g.

```
$css = '';
foreach($balls as $ball) {
    $css .= $ball->getCssRule();
}
echo $css;
```

Of course, you could also move that code into an instance method in `Balls`.