# Can I debug::dump() all objects in fuelphp?

Tags: debugging, fuelphp

In fuel you can Debug::dump($some_variable or $some_array or $some_object). You get something like

Variable #1:
object(Model_Order)#19 (9) {

with a whole bunch of other stuff following it. Is there any hack or code to dump all of the objects? If this one is #19 there has to be more I don't know about right?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way to get all defined objects from PHP but you can add mechanisms into your code to keep track of all instances if that's what you really want. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475569/get-all-instances-of-a-class-in-php)

If you are not sure what's going on in your code you might want to look into using proper debugging tools such as xdebug so you can have a better understanding of what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

get_defined_vars() was what I was really after and shows all of the variables that are defined null or otherwise.

Comment: Note that this only gives you the variables known in the current scope. In that sense, it's not an answer to the question, which asked about "all of the objects".

Comment: That's the reason why I didn't mark it as the answer, only just gave what I ended up doing as a solution.